# the problem is different animation, when creating and playing

Tags: animation, rigging, interpolation

When I create an animation by rotating the bone, I get the result that is different when I play an animation. The mesh is shifted during playback.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aaNqxWMJLMs&feature=youtu.be

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when the animation plays your 3D cursor is not the pivot point anymore, it's the bone.

Position the bones center at the position you want the object to pivot around.